# Android : Bluetooth Socket Connect Fails with : Service Discovery Failed

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I've got a tricky thing there, when i try to connect to my Bluetooth server written in C on my laptop with my Android phone (Acer liquid Z3, android ver : 4.2.2) i got this exception : Service Discovery Failed.
The weird thing is that on an another phone (Samsung Galaxy Grand2, android ver : 4.4.2) the BluetoothSocket is able to connect, send and recv datas.
Another weird thing is that i tried with my portable laptop which have integrated bluetooth and it works with both phone. I really don't know how to fix my problem. I've tried everything i saw on the web without success.

Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private BluetoothDevice BTHDevice;
    private BluetoothSocket BTHSocket;
    private OutputStream output;
    private String adrBluetooth = "00:15:83:0C:BF:EB";
    private final UUID MyUUID = UUID.fromString("5e3c369d-6557-40d6-9547-74e345f0f70d");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BTHAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    public void OnMenuConnect(MenuItem item)
    {
        BTHDevice = BTHAdapter.getRemoteDevice(adrBluetooth);

        try 
        {
            BTHSocket = BTHDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MyUUID);
            BTHAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            BTHSocket.connect();

            output = BTHSocket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```